# How to sort table through foreign table

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have some entities and code first creation.

```
public class Car
    {
        public int CarId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public ICollection<CarDetails> CarDetails;
    }
public class Detail
    {
        public int DetailId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public ICollection<CarDetails> CarDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

How to select Details and order them by Car->Title? These tables related by CarDetail table, that stores keys of both. I tried something like that                 details =

```
details.Where(x => x.DetailTypeId == id).OrderBy(x => x.DetailTypeId)
                        .ThenBy(x => x.CarDetails.First().Car.Title)
                        .ThenBy(x => x.Title)
```

It requires to be a IEnumerable to perform, but i need IQueryable.

Comment: why you need IQueryable exactly ?

Comment: Is this what you want? `var query = db.Car.Where(c=>c.CarId==id).OrderBy(x=>x.Title).SelectMany(x=>x.CarDetails);`

Comment: I needed IQuaryable for performance purposes. Thanks, guys, i've found my mistake.

Comment: Right query was simple `details.Where(x => x.DetailTypeId == id).OrderBy(x=>x.DetailTypeId).ThenBy(x=>x.CarDetails.FirstOrDefault().Car.Title).ThenBy(x => x.Title)`